# Eclipse - search and replace beginning of line

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to add two spaces to the beginning of each line in my selection. Every sane editor I've ever used let me do this using the equivalent of s/^/  /g (that's two spaces but SE collapses it into one). In Eclipse (Kepler), I go to Edit->Find/Replace, type '^' into the 'Find:' box, '  ' in the "Replace with" box, select 'Selected lines' under 'Scope', and check the 'Regular expressions' check box. When I click 'Replace All', nothing happens, except that the Find/Replace dialog says 'String Not Found' at the bottom. What incantation do I have to use to please Eclipse in this case?

Comment: If you are using regular expressions try \n in the "find field" and \n  followed by two spaces in the replace field...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

find :  `^.`

replace: `(two spaces)$0`

Comment: Thanks, this works (@Joe: although I didn't specify in my question, that it doesn't work for empty lines is actually a benefit for me :) )

Comment: Surprised that it didn't have any positive vote even after such a good solution!

Answer (score 2):

^ and $ are zero width anchors. You need to put some content with them. In this case you can capture a group and add spaces in front as follows:

Find: `^(.*)$`
Replace: `$1` (Two spaces followed by $1)

Comment: Thanks, this works - although I've never heard of zero width anchors not matching the expression though. Live & learn I guess.

Comment: @Roel it is not a rule, it depends on the implementation of the editor/program. Otherwise you could say, eclipse implemented right, and vim/sed/awk... all with this bug.